# Why does Apache drill change the column names when extractHeader is enabled?

Tags: sql, csv, apache-drill

I have the following data in the CSV file,

| PRODUCTID | PRODUCTNAME | SUPPLIERID | CATEGORYID | UNIT | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chais | 1 | 1 | 10 boxes x 20 bags | 18 |
| 2 | Chang | 1 | 1 | 24 - 12 oz bottles | 19 |
| 3 | Aniseed Syrup | 1 | 2 | 12 - 550 ml bottles | 10 |
| 4 | Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning | 2 | 2 | 48 - 6 oz jars | 22 |
| 5 | Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix | 2 | 2 | 36 boxes | 21.35 |

I've enabled extractHeader in the csv config of dfs plugin. 
Apache Drill version: apache-drill-1.21.0 
No. of drillbits: Single 
OS: Windows

While querying on the csv file using following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dfs.`/var/lib/PRODUCT.csv`
```

**Case 1:**
the output is
[image: drill-output]

Why does drill change the ID column name like that?

**Case 2:**
It does some more modifications when we have special characters in column name. 
For example -

`#UNITS` is changed to `col_UNITS`

`FINANCIAL$RECORD` is changed to `FINANCIAL_RECORD`

Is there any criteria on which these changes are made?

---

The **problem** with this is that while making a SELECT query with the original column names, we don't get any output. I've tried to go through the documentation and the JIRAs in Apache Drill but didn't find anything helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll try to provide an answer concerning allowed characters in column names but perhaps as a workaround you could set extractHeader to false and name your columns yourself while skipping the header row using an OFFSET clause: `select columns[0] as PRODUCTID, columns[1] as PRODUCTNAME, ... offset 1`

Comment: @DzamoNorton I want extractHeader property as true because it handles a lot of cases for me by returning all columns data in separate columns unlike when it's false.
For eg:
`SELECT * FROM ...`

when extractHeader is false the output will be in a single string; but not when it's true.